# Get last field using awk substr

Tags: unix, awk, substr

I am trying to use `awk` to get the name of a file given the absolute path to the file.
For example, when given the input path `/home/parent/child/filename` I would like to get `filename` 
I have tried:

```
awk -F "/" '{print $5}' input
```

which works perfectly.
However, I am hard coding `$5` which would be incorrect if my input has the following structure:

```
/home/parent/child1/child2/filename
```

So a generic solution requires always taking the *last* field (which will be the filename).

Is there a simple way to do this with the awk substr function?

Comment: as someone pointed out using `basename` is the official way of doing this, using `awk` for this is not good to put it lightly. :D

Answer (score 309, accepted):

Use the fact that `awk` splits the lines in fields based on a field separator, that you can define. Hence, defining the field separator to `/` you can say:

```
awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' input
```

as `NF` refers to the number of fields of the current record, printing `$NF` means printing the last one.

So given a file like this:

```
/home/parent/child1/child2/child3/filename
/home/parent/child1/child2/filename
/home/parent/child1/filename
```

This would be the output:

```
$ awk -F"/" '{print $NF}' file
filename
filename
filename
```

Comment: It works perfectly. I didnt think about $NF variable. Thanks for your immediate simple and effective answer.

Comment: For the penult one, use `$(NF-1)`.

Comment: Was writing a script to work with some docker commands and this did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 39):

In this case it is better to use `basename` instead of `awk`:

```
 $ basename /home/parent/child1/child2/filename
 filename
```

Comment: @Mari *F.Y.I* `dirname` does the opposite and strips file not the path.

Answer (score 7):

If you're open to a Perl solution, here one similar to fedorqui's awk solution:

```
perl -F/ -lane 'print $F[-1]' input
```

`-F/` specifies `/` as the field separator
`$F[-1]` is the last element in the `@F` autosplit array

Comment: Thanks. This helped me to get last but one field.     perl -F"/" -lane 'print $F[-2]' input

Comment: this worked for me when receiving from piped input.  Totally forgot about perl.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use `bash` [parameter substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```
$ foo="/home/parent/child/filename"
$ echo ${foo##*/}
filename
$ foo="/home/parent/child/child2/filename"
$ echo ${foo##*/}
filename
```

Answer (score 5):

Like 5 years late, I know, thanks for all the proposals, I used to do this the following way:

```
$ echo /home/parent/child1/child2/filename | rev | cut -d '/' -f1 | rev
filename
```

Glad to notice there are better manners

Answer (score 3):

*It should be a comment to the basename answer but I haven't enough point.*

If you do not use double quotes, `basename` will not work with path where there is space character:

```
$ basename /home/foo/bar foo/bar.png
bar
```

**ok with quotes " "**

```
$ basename "/home/foo/bar foo/bar.png"
bar.png
```

**file example**

```
$ cat a
/home/parent/child 1/child 2/child 3/filename1
/home/parent/child 1/child2/filename2
/home/parent/child1/filename3

$ while read b ; do basename "$b" ; done < a
filename1
filename2
filename3
```

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm like 3 years late on this but....
you should consider parameter expansion, it's built-in and faster.

if your input is in a var, let's say, $var1, just do `${var1##*/}`. Look below

```
$ var1='/home/parent/child1/filename'
$ echo ${var1##*/}
filename
$ var1='/home/parent/child1/child2/filename'
$ echo ${var1##*/}
filename
$ var1='/home/parent/child1/child2/child3/filename'
$ echo ${var1##*/}
filename
```

Answer (score 0):

you can skip all of that complex regex :

```
 echo '/home/parent/child1/child2/filename' | 

 mawk '$!_=$-_=$NF' FS='[/]'
                                  filename
```

**2nd to last** :

```
 mawk '$!--NF=$NF' FS='/'
                           child2
```

**3rd last** field :

```
 echo '/home/parent/child1/child2/filename' | 

 mawk '$!--NF=$--NF' FS='[/]'
 
                    child1
```

**4th-last** :

```
 mawk '$!--NF=$(--NF-!-FS)' FS='/'

 echo '/home/parent/child000/child00/child0/child1/child2/filename' |
                                     child0
 echo '/home/parent/child1/child2/filename'
             parent
```

***major caveat*** :

```
- `gawk/nawk` has a slight discrepancy with `mawk` regarding 

   - how it tracks multiple,
   - and potentially conflicting, decrements to `NF`, 

   - so other than the 1st solution regarding last field, 
   - the rest for now, are only applicable to `mawk-1/2`
```

Answer (score 0):

just realized it's much much cleaner this way in `mawk/gawk/nawk` :

```
echo '/home/parent/child1/child2/filename' | …
```

'

```
awk ++NF FS='.+/' OFS=      # updated such that 
                            # root "/" still gets printed
```

'

```
filename
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use:

```
    sed -n 's/.*\/\([^\/]\{1,\}\)$/\1/p'
```

or

```
    sed -n 's/.*\/\([^\/]*\)$/\1/p'
```

Comment: At this point nobody's upvoted this answer, probably because it's comparably fugly :)