# fetch a text from string with different length/pattern

Tags: awk, sed, fetch, extract, cut

I have a favor to ask for how to get the **TextN** from a string where there are different length/pattern before the TextN.  Cut, sed and awk? any example, I appreciate.

```
2018/08/09-20:45:50.671483-06359-06359-433191088669655042-004- TextN
2018/08/09-20:45:50.668677-06359-06359-002-006-  TextN
2018/08/09-20:45:50.668677-063-063-002-006-  TextN
```

Thank you in advance.

Sorry, ** was part code tag.

Comment: Please edit your Q to show your exact input text, the required output from that same text, your best effort to solve the problem with exact text of any error messages. Do you know about `sed 's/targStr/replStr/' file` (where replStr can be empty, i.e. `s/targStr//'`. Unless your data rely includes `*` chars, please remove them as they complicate an regexp that might be needed). Good luck.

Comment: if you just want the last field of line, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921544/get-last-field-using-awk-substr .. you can set a custom field delimiter using `-F` option, default is whitespaces which may be the case for you...

Answer (score 1):

if the text is wrapped in double stars and don't exist elsewhere...

```
$ awk -F'**' '{print $2}' file

TextN
TextN
TextN
```

otherwise post a more representative example.

Also with `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/.*\*\*([^*]+)\*\*.*/\1/' file
```

If the textN doesn't have spaces in them and if it's the last field separated with spaces...

```
$ awk '{print $NF}' file
```

since, characters, spaces have special meaning you have to pick your sample input carefully...

Comment: Sorry karakfa. I added ** around TextN  by accident.  I will explore your methods. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I just realized on my logs, i just need to skip first column, then extract all texts after that. like this.  cat logs.txt | awk '{ $1=""; print}'

Answer (score 0):

To complete @karakfa's `awk` example, using `sed`:

`sed -i -E "s/.*\*\*([a-zA-Z]+)\*\*/\1/" <your-text-file>`

The previous example works only if your `TextN` is matched by `[a-zA-Z]`. You can also use something more sophisticated or add other chars. In case you don't actually know what chars will be there:

`sed -i -E "s/.*\*\*(.+)\*\*/\1/" <your-text-file>`

In case your string is not in a file but is an environment variables or just a variable:

`echo $line | sed -E "s/.*\*\*(.+)\*\*/\1/"`