# Remove all path string from relative path

Tags: awk, sed, grep, posix

The following strings are in an html file that is a subset of the strings I have to work with:

```
content/css/dashboard.css
content/pages/icon-apache.png
content/js/dashboard-commons.js
sbadmin2-1.0.7/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
```

I'm trying to remove all the path and only leave the file name, so it would be like this:

```
dashboard.css
icon-apache.png
dashboard-commons.js
jquery.min.js
```

I'm trying to find an approach that doesn't involve just getting all cases one by one and use `sed` to replace it, but a generic way to do it.

**In short**:

- A regex to find the pattern (multi-level directory path) in the html file and remove it

**Edit**: I'm looking for a solution that works on linux, preferably that doesn't involves scripting or installing tools.

**Edit 2**: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921544/get-last-field-using-awk-substr) partially answers my question. With the answer provided there, I can now get the last part of the path. But I'm still looking for a regex pattern for extracting the list of strings from the html file.

**Edit 3**: As requested, here are a few examples:

```
<link href="sbadmin2-1.0.7/dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="content/css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="content/css/theme.blue.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="sbadmin2-1.0.7/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="sbadmin2-1.0.7/bower_components/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="sbadmin2-1.0.7/bower_components/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get last field using awk substr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921544/get-last-field-using-awk-substr)

Comment: For the HTML question, you have to provide us with an example so we know where these strings come from. Are they part of <a href="..."> or where do they come from.

Comment: Why not think about removing what is not needed with an RE? For example with sed: `sed 's:.*/::'`

Comment: Also, you ask for a regex to parse your HTML. [**Never** parse HTML or XML with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8344060) you might meet the pony.

Comment: @Thor that was my intention when asking the question. But I'm not familiar with sed/awk/grep to come up with the most appropriate regex for the job.

Answer (score 1):

from the full path

```
$ awk -F/ '{print $NF}' file

dashboard.css
icon-apache.png
dashboard-commons.js
jquery.min.js
```

from the html

```
$ awk -F'"' '/<link|script/{n=split($2,a,"/"); print a[n]}' file.html

sb-admin-2.css
dashboard.css
theme.blue.css
bootstrap.min.js
excanvas.min.js
jquery.flot.js
```

assumes one link/script tag per line.

Answer (score -2):

You should use basename for that

J.F.

```
basename content/css/dashboard.css
```

gives

```
dashboard.css
```

Comment: Sorry but I cannot see how that answers my question

Comment: basename content/css/dashboard.css gives you what you want dashboard.css

Comment: Suppose I have a list with 100 of strings like this, and the base name does not repeat. Your suggestion is to have a 100 replace commands, one for each base name, right? If so, I stated that it is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You can also pipe the data through `rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev`.